# Codehelp: Seeking column, and format cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a little problem with my macrocode, and need your advice. Here my base macrocode:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NurZumUeben()

'oberste Zeile löschen, fixieren und linksbündig ausrichten
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
With ActiveWindow
   .SplitColumn = 0
   .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Jede zweite Zeile schattieren
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Zeile, ZeilenNr As Integer
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
   .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
   .Borders.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
ZeilenNr = 2
For Zeile = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With Rows(Zeile)
        If .Hidden = False Then
            If ZeilenNr Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .Borders.Weight = xlThin
                .Borders.ColorIndex = 16
                ZeilenNr = ZeilenNr + 1
            Else
                ZeilenNr = ZeilenNr + 1
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next Zeile
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'oberste Zeile einfärben
Rows("1:1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With




'Spalte_suchen&formatieren
Dim iLeSpa     As Integer
Dim iSpalte    As Integer
Dim bGefunden  As Boolean

iLeSpa = IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(1, Columns.Count)), Cells(1, _
  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, Columns.Count)

For iSpalte = 1 To iLeSpa
   If Cells(1, iSpalte).Value = "click_thru_pct" Then
     bGefunden = True
     Exit For
  End If
Next iSpalte

If bGefunden Then
  With Range(Cells(2, iSpalte), Cells(5000, iSpalte))
     .Replace What:="%", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
     Range("K1") = 100
     Range("K1").Copy
     .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide
     .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
     Range("K1").Clear
  End With
Else
  MsgBox "Die Überschrift  ""click_thru_pct""  wurde nicht gefunden.", _
     48, "   Hinweis für " & Application.UserName
End If

End Sub
```

Once thank you all who can help. Unfortunately, I get the final formatting not go quite

Here are the results: [example](http://www.civelek.com/space-anomaly.com/excel.PNG)

I did not want to color the entire column but only the top row. In addition, the lower empty fields with ugly 0.00% formatted constantly.

Furthermore, I noticed that after the coloration of the first line, the field K1 is visible. That is with me unfortunately impractical because these Excel documents can also go differently in the row.

Here is the document on which you can test it if necessary.
[example](http://www.civelek.com/space-anomaly.com/report.xlsb)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change modular function to calculate the for loop variable. I see no purpose in using a separate variable for this. Change this:

```
ZeilenNr = 2
    For Zeile = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With Rows(Zeile)
            If .Hidden = False Then
                If ZeilenNr Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders.ColorIndex = 16
                    ZeilenNr = ZeilenNr + 1
                Else
                    ZeilenNr = ZeilenNr + 1
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Zeile
```

To this:

```
    For Zeile = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With Rows(Zeile)
            If .Hidden = False Then
                If Zeile Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
                    .Borders.ColorIndex = 16
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Zeile
```

I apologize if I am missing something here. Also, I cannot view the examples you provided because the site requires a login and it is not in English. Sorry again.

Comment: I thank you for your advice and for pointing out my sample file. I will change it immediately.
If you could test it on my Excel spreadsheet I would be deeply grateful.

Comment: You will need to implement Erik's answer as well. Formatting a cell will cause it to be included in the usedrange (I didn't see the bottom portion of your code earlier).

Comment: Sorry I think I did not express myself properly. Two thinks goes still wrong by execute eric's advice. 1) i would not colouer the whole column, only the first row. 2) The last top Colum k are deleted. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within your existing code,

1. Substitute `5000` with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`
2. Substitute `Range("K1").Clear` with `Range("K1").ClearContents`

Comment: Sorry I think I did not express myself properly. Two thinks goes still wrong by execute your advice. 1) i would not colouer the whole column, only the first row. 2) The last top Colum k are deleted. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `For Zeile = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`, you could use

```
For Zeile = 2 To ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count-1
```

`.UsedRange` is not always properly reset. You sample seems a good candidate for `.CurrentRegion`